# How to test my podspec file without having to commit my changes all the time?

Tags: ios, git, cocoa, cocoapods

I am writing a library as a pod (used `pod lib create`) and I am trying to figure out how to structure my files since I have a mix of static libraries, non-arc files and arc files. Thus, I am making several changes and then run `pod spec lint NAME.podspec` in order to pass validation.

I **haven't** specified any remote yet (that should be fine for now, right?) so my podspec looks like that:

```
s.source = { :git => "/Volumes/Development/Pods/POD_NAME", :commit => "aaf6d439349bf05a7399db3cd3b0fe3980eef1f7" }
```

But then that means that every time I make a change, I need to commit my changes and replace the new commit sha-1 in my podspec, save, and lint again.

But that doesn't seem the correct way to do it, right? Is my workflow wrong here?

Comment: In podfiles :path can be used to specify a local path for a pod. Don't know if it works, but see if you can pass :path to source.

Comment: path is no longer a supported method https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-packager/issues/32

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `:head` in your `Podfile` if you're testing it that way ([docs](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod))

Otherwise you can leave the `:commit` key out of the source hash and it should pull the newest source. Just leave the `:git` key.

Comment: But in my case, the problem comes from the podspec, not the podfile (which is using `pod "POD_NAME", :path => "../POD_NAME.podspec"` and seems to work fine)